Collection expression with type IList<T>
Given
public IList<int> Numbers { get; } = [] 

What assumptions can I safely make about the type of Numbers?
For example, will it always return false for IsFixedSize and IsReadOnly?
Obviously Array.Empty<int>() also implements IList<int>, but has a fixed size.
Right now, it seems to be a List<int>. But what are the plans going forwards?

Will the compiler analyse the code to determine whether the collection is ever added to or removed from?
Or will the compiler always assume that IList is always expected to be mutable & non-fixed size?

Is there something in the docs that explains this?

The idea is the exact type of the [] expression is an implementation detail that can change from version to version. If you give the property an IList<int> type, the items provided by the interface contract are all you're supposed to use or rely on.

"Is there something in the docs that explains this?" Did you look at the documentation for collection initializers?  In what way was the documentation insufficient to answer your questions?

Are you saying that in future, the compiler could switch the List<int> for Array.Empty<int>()?

From this. "A compliant implementation is free to: 1. Use an existing type that implements that interface. 2. Synthesize a type that implements the interface." That is about as much as you can rely on. The values returned are completely dependent upon the underlying implementaion and cannot therefore be guaranteed to be any specific value.

I found this comment on Mutable Interface Translation which includes the sentence "The value must support all mutation methods (like IList.RemoveAt".
But it's unclear to me whether that always applies.

@Rob That specific option is unlikely, since Array while Array does implement IList, it would have odd results for, eg the Add() method. But they might choose to use some new Span-like collection type in the future in order to improve performance.

Thanks @JoelCoehoorn. This is my confusion. Technically, Array does (pretend to) implement IList<T> interface, but it throws for add/remove operations.
The problem is that the collection classes do not honour LSP, otherwise it would not matter what implementation is used.

The spec you linked is the answer: "The value must support all mutation methods" and that is for Given a target type or ICollection<T> or IList<T>:

To quote the specification:

Mutable interface translation
Given a target type or ICollection<T> or IList<T>:

The value must return false when queried for ICollection<T>.IsReadOnly.

The value generated is allowed to implement more interfaces than required. Specifically, implementing IList<T> even when only targeting ICollection<T>. However, in that case:

The value must support all mutation methods (like IList<T>.RemoveAt).


So with IList<int> numbers = [] you are guaranteed to get an implementation of IList<int> that supports the full interface, including its mutating operations. That means that it will not be Array<int>. But other than that, you don’t get any guarantee.
But you also shouldn’t need more information about the concrete type. You have specified the variable/member to have the type IList<int> so that’s all that you should rely on. If you require a specific implementation type, then use that particular type for the variable/member.
So if the compiler currently synthesizes an List<int>, then that’s the compilers decision and an implementation detail. It could change its mind at any time and later use a type SpecialIListImplementationThatIsNotAccessible<int> and you wouldn’t have any control over it. But it would still fulfill the IList<int> interface.

I found that part of the spec. I guess I wasn't clear from the text whether "However, in that case" refers to the case of "targeting ICollection<T>" or the more general case.
